# Rails 4: Disable automatic CSS sanitizing when using built-in HTML sanitize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitize

I'm building an application that has a HTML GUI interface to create, move and edit boxes (`div`) inside a container `div`. These boxes get assigned inline styles when editing, these inline styles are saved to the database and are output in the views:

```
<%= sanitize raw(@slide.content) %>
```

I want to sanitize the HTML itself, to avoid someone hacking in, for instance, a script tag, through sending that by editing what's sent to the server when the boxes are saved.

Rails 4 has a helper method `sanitize` available through the class [ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html). When I use this with a test `content` value that contains a malicious `<script>` tag, the script gets removed just fine. But sanitizing the content also strips CSS properties inside the style tag that are **necessary** for the boxes, like `top`, `left`, `position`, etc.

In the linked documentation, it's stated that `sanitize` will automatically use the function `sanitize_css` when it comes across a *style* attribute:

> **sanitize_css(style)**
>
> Sanitizes a block of CSS code. Used by sanitize when it comes across a style attribute.

I do *not* want this behaviour of `sanitize`. How can I disable sanitize using `sanitize_css`, to sanitize the HTML, but not the CSS?

Answer (score 3):

You can allow any attributes and tags you need, so rails will skip them.

```
sanitize raw(@slide.content), tags: %w(table tr td ul li), attributes: %w(style href title)
```

Speaking about CSS rules themselves, it's a bit harder to allow additional rules, but still possible. You can monkey patch the `HTML::WhiteListSanitizer` class (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c71c8a962353642ee44b5cc6ed68dc18322eea72/actionpack/lib/action_view/vendor/html-scanner/html/sanitizer.rb). There are several attributes that can help.

Comment: The style tag is not the problem here, maybe I should have worded it better. The style tag itself does not get removed, but the majority of CSS attributes defined inside it do. So adding it to the allowed HTML tag attributes does not help much.

Comment: tags here refer to actual tags (e.g. <a> or <div>), but attribute are the attributes of tags (e.g. <a href="..."> or <div style="...">). So attributes here should do the trick.

Comment: I'm sorry, my choice of words was confusing again. Okay, let's say `<a>` is a tag, the `style` in `<a style="...">` is an HTML attribute, and `top: 30px` is a CSS property. What gets removed are some of the *properties*, not the HTML *attribute*. What your command does is allow the `style` *attribute* to pass the sanitizer, yet it does not help letting the *CSS property* pass through it.

Comment: It is really strange. How these css properties are set in your code?

Comment: Inside the `style` tag, as I explained. I have something like `<div style="top:30px;position:absolute;background-color:#fff">`, and what comes out after sanitizing is `<div style="background-color:#fff">`. The cause of this is the automatic execution of `sanitize_css` **inside** `sanitize`.

Comment: Finally, I got it! :) my fault, I was thinking, that rails doesn't touch css code itself. I have explored some source codes and it seems that the only thing you can do about it is to do monkey patching of HTML::WhiteListSanitizer class (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c71c8a962353642ee44b5cc6ed68dc18322eea72/actionpack/lib/action_view/vendor/html-scanner/html/sanitizer.rb). There are several attributes that are used while sanitizing :) hope it helps!

Comment: Glad we finally understand each other here. And thanks, that's a good suggestion! You could edit that into your answer, so I can try it out on Monday and probably mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

In your `config/application.rb` file:

```
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_tags = nil
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_attributes = nil
```

safe lists found here: [loofah html5 safelist](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah/blob/master/lib/loofah/html5/safelist.rb)