# Rails 5 whitelist css property for sanitize helper

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sanitize

I need to allow inline `"style=position: absolute;"` output by `sanitize(post.content)`.   I found [documentation for Rails 4](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/ClassMethods/sanitized_allowed_css_properties%3D) that said

```
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_css_properties = ['position']
```

in application.rb would add properties to the whitelist, but I can't find documentation whether this is still the case for Rails 5 and it doesn't appear to be working after restarting the server multiple times.  Is there a way to easily add whitelisted css properties?  This [answer for Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623281/rails-4-disable-automatic-css-sanitizing-when-using-built-in-html-sanitize) suggests a monkey patch, but I'm not sure where or how to do so.

Update: installing [gem rails-deprecated_sanitized](https://github.com/kaspth/rails-deprecated_sanitizer) allowed the above config line to work, so it looks like sanitized_allowed_css_properties is deprecated.  Surely there's a way to do this in Rails 5?  I can't step back to 4, and I need to whitelist inline style position in order to get a third party plugin to work (CKEditor + Iframely)

Answer (score 1):

Working off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35070433/how-can-i-allow-source-tags-through-rails-4-sanitize) and the list of default allowed properties [here](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah/blob/master/lib/loofah/html5/whitelist.rb), I ended up adding

```
default_tags = Loofah::HTML5::WhiteList::ALLOWED_CSS_PROPERTIES.add('position')
```

to application.rb, which allowed position to pass through sanitize by default.  Not sure how safe this is.

Answer (score 1):

I have absolutely no idea of what @Jim Hogan tried to do with his answer. I tried it and it did not work. So I spent a bit of time to analyze everything and I found my own answer:

We got a helper named `sanitize_css` from `ActionController::Base.helpers`.

So why not using it by extracting the raw style ? Nokogiri is included in Rails > 4.

```
  def patched_sanitize(html_tag_string)
    sanitize html_tag_string, tags: %w(a b strong), attributes: manual_attributes
  end

  def manual_attributes
    attributes = %w(href target align)
    attributes << 'style' unless style_unsafe?

    attributes
  end

  def style_unsafe?
    ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize_css(style_attributes_of(string)).empty?
  end

  def style_attributes_of(string)
    Nokogiri::HTML(self.body).xpath('//body').children.map{|e| e.attr('style')}.join(' ')
  end
```

EDIT: Ok I think I finally understand what OP wanted to say. And for a reason, it DOES work only if one does what I do in this answer. So my answer is complementary I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple CSS properties to whitelist in Loofah for **Rails 5 sanitizer**.

```
Loofah::HTML5::WhiteList::ALLOWED_CSS_PROPERTIES.merge %w(position background-image left list-style min-width top z-index)
```

Add above line in `application.rb`
(Again not sure how safe this is)

Comment: You can properly tag your code by surrounding it with " ` "